# Add MS SQL Server to virtual machine in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to get TDE in Azure. I read that it's possible only on a virtual machine. I built the virtual box, but didn't add SQL Server when it was created. Can I just install SQL or will I have to start from scratch and recreate the virtual machine.

Thank you for your help.

Ernie_M

Comment: Not 100% sure *(thats why posting as comment)* - you have to install from scratch or side by side provision another VM with SQL Server and then change your application to point to the new VM and delete the former one.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Azure Transparent Data Encryption [**is possible**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn948096%28v=sql.120%29.aspx), but it is currently still in preview.

If you do not want to accept the supplemental terms of use for this then you can simply install SQL Server on the VM you just created or provision a new machine and use one of the numerous pre-built images that are available.

I would recommend you simply spin up a new machine as it is relatively painless, offers configuration by Microsoft, and ensures you have a SQL Server License since it is bundled with the VM image's pricing.

If you install software on a standalone VM you need a license for that software since the basic VM image is likely priced for and only includes a Windows license. There are a lot of plans and maybe you have a MSDN license... you'd have to check the details that pertain to your situation/subscription etc. to know that aspect of the decision for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to specify if you are referring to `Azure SQL Database` (PaaS) or `SQL Server on an Azure VM` (IaaS). As already noted TDE with Azure SQL Database is only available with V12 which is only available in certain regions.

If you an Azure VM is what you are working with you can implement TDE in SQL Server after the VM is built, even after SQL Server is installed.

An Azure VM built from Azure's catalog with SQL Server pre-installed you are paying for the VM resources plus SQL Server licensing. With just a built Azure VM you have to provide the license for SQL Server (and the media).